# Active Directory authentication type encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory

In Active Directory, Authentication is not working when i include Authentication Types as Encryption(AuthenticationTypes.Encryption).

I am getting following error,
**Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.**

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, sUsername, sPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Encryption);
```

If i use without authentication type as below code, its working fine.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, sUsername, sPassword);
```

I cant able to find the root cause for this.

I also checked with following url, but samething thing happpening,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is your application pool using a different Identity than this `sUsername`?

Comment: yes...i have tried Anonymous Authentication  specific User(IUSR) and also Appliction pool identity